# Error when using Writer.Close() function within my Pandas and Openpyxl code

Tags: python, pandas, openpyxl

I have written a code which combines some CSV files into a single Excel file, and ended the 'writer' with the code:

```
writer.save()
writer.close()
```

However, I get the following error when trying to then open that file after the code has finalised:

```
We found a problem with some content in 'the file.xlsx'. Do you want us to try to recover as much as we can? If you trust the source of this workbook, click Yes.'
```

This seems to purely be related to the 'Writer.Close()' aspect, as without it I don't get the error. However, instead I cannot open the file as it states that someone else is using it (ie - openpyxl)

I'm not sure if relevant, but my file system runs on a OneDrive cloud based system.

My current plan beyond the 'writer.close()' is to pause the script to allow me to print the excel to PDF (I found this to be unreliable via Python), and then 'hit continue' to continue with exporting the PDF via Email.

Any ideas on how to resolve this error?

Answer (score 0):

With out seeing more of your code and maybe an example of the data you are writing it's tough to make any assumptions. Based on the error you are experiencing it is likely due to the inputs/data going into the actual xlsx file that is causing the issue and not with the actual 'writer'. This is Excel saying that data in your file is 'corrupted' from their standards perspective and needs to be fixed.

You should be able to do a 'recovery' of the file through excel and it will identify the problem spots in your file which you can then back track into your python program and properly address to eliminate the probelm.

Comment: See, I thought this might be the case as well. However, if I just run the script up to the 'writer.save()' point and eliminate the 'close'. It opens fine without any errors.

If it wasn't for the fact that I want to continue the script with the email aspect, I would just end it there